# NullPointer Exception on android image gallery onselected

Tags: java, android

I am using android image gallery,I want to select image tag id by click on gallery item and put that id in to `HashMap` (param_ids). I used the following code.but this gave me a `NullPointerException` on this line before I clicked on gallery item.

```
  param_ids.put("facial_appearance_id",view.getTag().toString());
```

this will working fine on `android 2.3` but this will give an `NullPointerException` on `android 4.0.3`. so how can I slove this issue?

code

```
Gallery faceGallery= (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
faceGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
    param_ids.put("facial_appearance_id",view.getTag().toString());
            }
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
 });
```

Comment: Show, how and where did you initialized `param_ids` field?

Comment: have you defined param_ids as static?

Comment: Have you initialized the `param_ids` ?

Comment: i initialized it this way  HashMap<String, String> param_ids=new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: Where do you bind the data into your gallery ?

Comment: Show where is your adapter to bind the data into the Gallery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Gallery` `OnItemClickListener()`.

```
 faceGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            //Do your stuff

        }
    });
```